# Updating few components after successful action finished

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rendering

I'm updating my redux state with action call in React.js and as now `componentWillReciveNewProps()` is depriciated I wanted to use
`static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` to update my component but as I can see it's called to early, I mean first 
-> the action is called 
-> `static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState)` is called 
-> and action_success and updating redux

But my component stayed not updated.
Do you have any idea how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use componentDidUpdate() ? https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: @Epitouille I've tried it as well but still it gets called before successful action is finised.

Comment: Can you show a little of code?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to be doing anything special here with `getDerivedStateFromProps` or similar. It sounds more like the component update is being blocked by something, maybe react-router? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking
(we need to see more code to help further)